# Using static methods in Java for scalability

Tags: java

In developing a Java based backend using the Google App Engine, it occurred to me that since I end up paying by the number of instances created, it obviously makes sense to design the code in such a way as to minimize the memory usage. This has made me wonder whether it makes sense to use static methods as much as possible, the reasoning being that static methods only get created once in memory. Of course the methods would have to be immutable and thus not allow for the use of private static fields.

My assumption here is that calling a static method 1 million times is more efficient in memory usage that creating 1 million instances of the class that holds that method.

Does this reasoning make sense or am I possibly overlooking something about the use of static methods?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what a "mutable method" looks like, and how it is different from an "immutable method". Also, why did you care to point out that "static methods only get created once in memory"? How often are non-static methods created, in your opinion?

Comment: Immutable meaning that no state is stored when the method is called. I am fairly certain that static methods only exist once in memory.

Comment: Write the code. Test it. If you have a performance issue, _profile_ the code. THEN after you know where the bottlenecks are, optimize where appropriate.  Before that point, don't worry about it.  You are going off on tangents based on a misunderstanding of how things work, this is time that could be spent working on the real problem.  IOW, you're overthinking this.

Comment: Methods belong to classes. Classes can be loaded only *once* (by a Classloader), regardless of whether their methods are static, final, mutable, immutable, or whatever. Are you otherwise creating "millions" of objects just for fun, so that you can call static methods on them? If this is the case, then, yes, indeed, maybe you could omit creating the "millions" of objects, and go back to static methods. Or, preferably, to non-reentrant C code.

Answer (score 2):

Instance methods get created once only too. There is no clever optimization for you to do here, and basically you're deciding whether or not you'll be doing bad design by making everything static. There are no monetary savings to be had here.

You don't seem to quite understand how the internals work, so it's better that you don't worry too much about it. You're also comparing calling a static method 1 million times vs. creating 1 million instances. That's apples and oranges as they don't do the same thing at all. An equivalent comparison would be if you had 1 million data objects and you called a static method with one of those as a parameter.

Methods aren't what you need to care about, it's the data you're working with that uses memory.

Comment: Singletons typically use a static method, yet that method only exists once. Without a singleton and some common class instance, each time I needed to use the method I would have to instantiate a new instance.

Comment: @AndroidDev oh please. Don't confuse yourself more by adding singletons to the mix. Trust me, you're not nearly as clever as you think you are, and if you imagine you'll be saving money you're wrong. First get a better understanding about the internal workings before you attempt micro-optimization. Then you'll also understand that micro-optimization results in micro savings. If you think that your alternatives are static methods and calling methods like `new Foo().bar();`, then you need even **more** help with design. Of course you won't create an object **just** to call a method.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I don't advocate "ignorance is bliss", on the contrary. The problem of the question is the amount of assumptions vs. the amount of experience. I can't dispense years of experience in a single answer, so I can at least inform the asker that his assumptions are baseless.

Comment: "Trust me, you're not nearly as clever as you think.." - The type of comment that never gets your response selected. Please leave your arrogance out of SO.

Comment: @AndroidDev it's not arrogance, it's the truth. I don't know about your skillset when developing for Android, but your question showed a clear lack of understanding of the internal workings of a regular JVM. Hope you learned to assume a little less from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Where you go wrong here is that "the amount of instances" is not the same as the "amount of data". Let's say you crawl and process Wikipedia. What is important is how much data is in memory at any given time, not so much how it is distributed across instances. Obviously, doing stuff wrong is always possible, but static methods won't save you from that ;-)